# Making a Private Sub-Type Internal or Public

Tags: swift, access-control

Occasionally, the Swift compiler will synthesize a sub-type for you when you conform a type to a protocol. From my experience, these types are given the access level of `private`. This is usually fine, but I have come across a case in which I want to be able to access the private subtype in an extension held in a different file (same module, in case you are wondering) which you [apparently can't do](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html).

Is it possible to give the type a higher access level without having to write it by hand and take advantage of the synthesized code?

An example of where this happens is conformance to `Codable`. The `CodableKeys` sub-type is declared as `private` when it is synthesized, but you can make it any access level you want when you manually write it.

Here is an example of code that raises an error about this.

`Company.swift`:

```
class Company: Codable {
    let name: String
    let founded: Date

    init(name: String, founded: Date) {
        self.name = name
        self.founded = founded
    }
}
```

`Company+JSON.swift`:

```
extension Company {
    func json() -> JSON {
        let data: [String: JSON] = [
            CodingKeys.name: self.name
        ]
        return JSON.object(data)
    }
}
```

I get:

```
'CodingKeys' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
```

It wouldn't be hard to write the type for a type this size, but it quickly becomes a mess when you have multiple types with 9, 10, 11+ properties.

Comment: Can you give us a code sample that you experience problems with?

Comment: No, you don't have any control of `CodableKeys` if you don't write it. Same for the auto-generated `Codable` implementations. You either write it, or you take what you get. That said, if you're trying to make `CodableKeys` be `public` you're almost certainly exposing internal details you shouldn't. For `internal`, the answer is to put closely related things in the same file. Swift encourages larger files than ObjC does.

Comment: @Cristik I think I added what you want.

Comment: @CalebKleveter for that particular case you can just use a `JSONEncoder` to achieve the encoding. Are there any other concrete use cases that you need to work with?

Comment: @Cristik actually, I can't use `JSONEncoder`, unless I am missing an `exclude` option. The reason I am doing what I am in the example is because I need to add additional data to the JSON and not encode all the properties. If `JSONEncoder` can do that, I will use it :).

Comment: @CalebKleveter You can always implement a custom version of Encodable's `encode(to:)` method, if you need to encode in a different way.